# I have two vlans on the same router that can't ping each other

Tags: switch, router, vlan

I'm using the student version of cisco packet tracer 6.2.

I have two vlans that are connected to the same router but they can't ping each other. Here is the config from my router and my switch.

**My router:**

```
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
hostname Router
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.254
ip dhcp pool 10
network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
ip dhcp pool 20
network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
spanning-tree mode pvst
interface FastEthernet0/0
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
interface FastEthernet0/0.10
encapsulation dot1Q 10
ip address 192.168.10.254 255.255.255.0
interface FastEthernet0/0.20
encapsulation dot1Q 20
ip address 192.168.20.254 255.255.255.0
interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
duplex auto
speed auto
shutdown
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
ip classless
ip flow-export version 9
no cdp run
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login
end
```

**and my switch:**

```
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
hostname Switch
spanning-tree mode pvst
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 10
interface FastEthernet0/2
switchport access vlan 20
interface FastEthernet0/3
switchport mode trunk
ports 4-24 are not configured. 
interface Vlan1
no ip address
shutdown
line con 0
line vty 0 4
login
line vty 5 15
login
end
```

Comment: Why is there only one port configured as a trunk of VLANs 10 and 20 on the router while the switch has two access ports, one with VLAN 10 and one with VLAN20?

Comment: How are you assigning the gateway for the hosts? You don't have that in your DHCP pools. A host will need a gateway in order to contact anything off its network.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, I forgot to assign the default gateway on the dhcp pools.

Comment: @TeunVink sorry the config was unreadable at first. Thanks for fixing it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the default gateway in the DHCP configurations.  You need one for each pool:

```
default-router 192.168.x.254
```